# cannot import name 'MultiRNNCell'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a python script that used to work normally last year, now when I tried to rerun it shows me this error (I upgraded TensorFlow):

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import MultiRNNCell, LSTMStateTuple
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'MultiRNNCell'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are moved to compat.v1:

```
tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(
    cells, state_is_tuple=True
)
tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(
    num_units, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True, activation=None, reuse=None,
    name=None, dtype=None, **kwargs
)
tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(
    c, h
)
```

Instead you can use tf.keras.layers.LSTM and tf.keras.layers.RNN libraries.